# Getting an "undefined index" error

Tags: php

I'm making an activation page that is getting mailed to the user after they register to the website, but i'm having an error in my code:

```
Undefined index: ActivationKey
```

the link the user will get will be like

```
website-url/activate.php?Username=user&ActivationKey=foobar
```

it gives the error on this line of code:

```
$ActivationKey = $_SESSION['ActivationKey'];
```

my code is the following:

```
<?PHP



//Include database connection details
require_once('config.php');

//Array to store validation errors
$errmsg_arr = array();

//Validation error flag
$errflag = false;

//Connect to mysql server
$link = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","XXX");
if(!$link) {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Select database
$db = mysql_select_db("monitron");
if(!$db) {
    die("Unable to select database");
}


//Start session
session_start();    


//check if Username is already in session and
//use it if it is
//else, grab it from GET
//use it from GET
if(!empty($_SESSION['Username'])){
$Username = $_SESSION['Username'];
}else if(isset($_GET['Username'])){
$_SESSION['Username'] = $_GET['Username'];
$Username = $_SESSION['Username'];
};


//Grab activationkey from session.

if(isset($_GET['ActivationKey'])){
$_SESSION['ActivationKey'] = $_GET['ActivationKey'];
};

$ActivationKey = $_SESSION['ActivationKey'];

echo $ActivationKey;
echo $Username;

//Create update query to update activation status
$qry = "UPDATE login SET ActivationStatus = 'Active' WHERE Username = '$Username'";
$result = @mysql_query($qry)

?>
```

i'd appreciate it if somebody could help me out on this :)

Comment: i think that line should move inside the if statement just before it.

Comment: what var_dump($_GET,$_SESSION) prints before this line?

Comment: var_dump($GET,$_SESSION) gives me
 array
  'Username' => string 'xvampx' (length=6)
  'Activationkey' => string 'df5097bfcf58e61af7c48603a47c5288' (length=32)
array
  'Username' => string 'xvampx' (length=6)

Comment: Activationkey ----- k is in small letters?

Comment: yes it is in small letters :)

Comment: if(isset($_GET['ActivationKey'])){
$_SESSION['ActivationKey'] = $_GET['ActivationKey'];
};
Why do you have semicolons ending the IF statement?

Answer (score 1):

You have the lines

```
if(isset($_GET['ActivationKey'])){
    $_SESSION['ActivationKey'] = $_GET['ActivationKey'];
};

$ActivationKey = $_SESSION['ActivationKey'];
```

But what if the if statement never is true, then there is no $_SESSION['ActivationKey'] and that is the error PHP is complaining about.

Comment: but it should be true, because in the link the activationkey is set. it should grab the string and put it into the $activationkey variable.

Comment: checkyour Username value ---- I guess it might be containing some space etc weird HTML char ---- what username you are supplying?

Comment: see my comment on the answer above, when i use var dump $GET $SESSION it displays the activationkey in GET but not in SESSION. so it's getting the username right.